# Opening big storage log file in vi

Tags: aix, vi, large-files

I have a Storage log in an AIX partition. When I try to edit the file with a vi command, I receive the following message: `ex: 0602-101 Out of memory saving lines for undo delete lines`

I don't want to extend the file limit to read the file. Instead of that, I want to delete some lines to reduce the file size.

How can I specify that I delete all the contents of the file except for the last 10000 lines?

I thought this was the right way, but didn't work well: `1,$-10000d`

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can use split command to break down that huge file into several smaller ones. Unfortunately i am on mobile now  so can't post an answer but see the related one:  http://askubuntu.com/a/870389/295286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *deleting* everything but the last 10000 lines using Vi, filter them out to a new file (you generally don't want to *edit* logfiles anyway).

```
$ tail -n 10000 logfile >logfile.tail
```

You may then replace `logfile` with `logfile.tail` if you wish:

```
$ mv logfile.tail logfile
```

Since some programs that write to logfiles may keep the logfile open for writing until the program exits, some new messages may be written to the old logfile even though it is replaced by the shorter version.  These log messages are lost.

To work around this:

```
$ cat logfile.tail >logfile
```

This will *truncate* `logfile` (emptying it without removing it) and then replace its contents with that of `logfile.tail`. This also means that no messages from programs that have `logfile` open for writing will be lost.

Also consider putting some sort of automatic logfile rotation in place to avoid overly large logfiles.